# ionic build android throws "Uh oh!" error after updating cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I just updated cordova via `sudo npm install -g cordova`

Now i have the problem, that everytime when i try to build the android app with `ionic run android --device` i get

```
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: TypeError: Uh oh!
Invalid Version: undefined
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

or `ionic build android`

```
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Error: Uh oh!
Invalid Version: undefined
```

IOS is working fine so i think it's a problem with android?

```
Android SDK Tools: 24.3.4
Android SDK Platform-tools: 23.0.1
Android SDK Build-tools: 23.0.2
SDK: Android 5.1.1 (API 22)
```

The combo i have:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.10
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.7.0 
ios-sim version: 4.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v0.12.7
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1 Build version 7B91b
```

Comment: have you set android-sdk and android-sdk-tools in the PATH? export PATH=$PATH:path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools:path/to/android-sdk/tools

Comment: yess, `echo $PATH` shows that android-sdk and android-sdk-tools are set. i had no problems to build apks, before updating cordov.

Comment: if is a problem with the upgrade try removing /platforms folder and then add android platform and try to build again.

Comment: thx mate, i removed android and added it again. The next error was that i have to install the cordova googleplayservices plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplayservices` (i have no idea for what i need this) but now it is working again.

Comment: The plugin has an uptade too? If not try with a fork

Comment: il you have removed the /platforms folder you probably must remove /plugins folder too and reinstall all of plugins.

Comment: I reinstalled all of the plugins, and now it's working like before. I thought they're reinstalled automatically if i remove and readd a platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file 'platforms.json' in the platforms folder is missing.
Run the commands to remove platforms and add platforms.

```
$ cordova platform rm android
$ cordova platform add android
```

Confirm this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me.

```
$ ionic state reset

$ ionic info
```

My system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.11
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.3
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version you are using:

```
sudo npm install cordova@5.4.0 -g
```

I originally installed the latest but since it won't build my stuff, I installed 5, which incidentally, installs 5.4.1 and I was getting the same error.

Downgraded to 5.4.0 and it works just fine.