# Failed to install 'cordova-universal-clipboard':

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I made an ionic project and succesfully converted it to ios app and installed it to my device successfully. However; after trying addding android platform to the project;

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

I had the following error;

```
Failed to install 'cordova-universal-clipboard': TypeError: Uh oh!
Path must be a string. Received undefined
```

Comment: May be a duplicate of : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981901/ionic-build-android-throws-uh-oh-error-after-updating-cordova/34585487](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981901/ionic-build-android-throws-uh-oh-error-after-updating-cordova/34585487)

Comment: thanks for the reply!